# Access VBA: How to count items of a ComboBox?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, count, vba, selection

In my `ComboBox` I have some items already selected.

I would like to count them with VBA. I was expecting to find something like the following string, but I get `Compile error: Argument not optional`.

```
Me.<ComboBox_name>.ItemData.Count
```

I also thought to use the following string but it gives me `0` items:

```
Me.<ComboBox_name>.ItemSelected.Count
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comboboxes are generally used for selecting or showing the selection of a single item, whereas listboxes naturally support multiple selections.

That said, if you're linking a multivalued* table field to a Combobox, for example, you could have a Combobox with multiple selections.  If that's the case, the only time the values will be available in the `.ItemsSelected` property is while the Combobox has focus and is dropped down.

A way to work around this is to assign the Combobox's `.Value` property to an array. The array will contain the selected values. You may count them by taking the upper bound of the array and adding 1:

```
Dim comboitems() as Variant
Dim count as Long

comboitems = yourcombobox.Value

' array is 0-based so add one to get the count
count = UBound(comboitems) + 1
```

If the array is multidimensional, you read the value this way:

```
' array is 0-based so add one to get the count
count = UBound(comboitems, [dimension]) + 1

' where [dimension] is a 1-based index equivalent to the 'column' of the data
```

I hope that helps!

> *Note: multivalued fields are usually ill-advised, as they are poorly
>   supported by Access and usually mean you should be normalizing your
>   tables, i.e. breaking out the multivalued field into another table.

Answer (score 8):

To count the options, it is:

```
Me!<ComboBox_name>.ListCount
```

or to be precise, in case you use column headings:

```
Me!<ComboBox_name>.ListCount - Abs(Me!<ComboBox_name>.ColumnHeads)
```

Comment: Thanks :-) You Saved me.